# webklex laravel-imap references in header

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I'm still working on getting a handle on email threads with the webklex laravel-imap package and I'm trying to make sense of the header info, mainly references. Basically, anytime I scrape the inbox and there's a new reply, I want to take the body of only that reply and make it into a comment on the front end (so save the body of that reply in the database)

I think one way to do this is to inject a token above the current message, so that when they respond I can parse anything up to that toeknized point.

Anyway, I'm using `$oMessage->getHeaderInfo()` to get the header and then I'm storing the message_id for each email as it comes in. I'm thinking I may need to store references as well so that I can keep track of the replies but I'm not fully making sense of the paramaters that I'm getting here:

```
        Message_id for original message
            <BN9PR12MB50662E9B5341983E744821B4D1159@BN9PR12MB5066.namprd12.prod.outlook.com>

        After I've replied to that email and the sender has responded back to me (total of 3 messages in thread now)

        in_reply_to: 
            <BYAPR12MB2904B9CD0C265DDBCBBB920288159@BYAPR12MB2904.namprd12.prod.outlook.com>
        Message_id: 
            <BN9PR12MB5066274555ED3DB67B7F001FD1159@BN9PR12MB5066.namprd12.prod.outlook.com>
        references: 
            <BN9PR12MB50662E9B5341983E744821B4D1159@BN9PR12MB5066.namprd12.prod.outlook.com><BYAPR12MB2904B9CD0C265DDBCBBB920288159@BYAPR12MB2904.namprd12.prod.outlook.com>
```

So, the message_id for the origin email is the first id in the references object, which makes sense. It seems like the `in_reply_to` is showing the message_id for the second message in the thread (my response to the origin email), and then the other id in the references object is the message_id of the current (third) email in the chain.

Does that sound correct? As long as I'm looking for the origin message_id in the references, then i should be able to track the thread through to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-Reply-To stores the message-id of the message directly being replied to.  This way threading email clients (like Thunderbird, not gmail), can show an entire tree of replies.  That’s why the system is so complicated: it is not just tracking a bunch of related emails, it’s tracking the exact relation of which message is a reply to which message.

This used to be considered important and is reflected in many older Email and News type clients.

Comment: As an addition, some newer email servers and protocols will use this information to track a simple “thread-id” (eg, gmail’s X-THREADID extension, or newer ActiveSyncs thread id), to make it simpler for clients that don’t care about the full tree.

Comment: I'm using outlook (office 365) so I'll have to see if that applies here, but otherwise I think I can make do with the references and in-reply-to. I think if I save the message_id of each message then I can check it against the reference of others and create a parent message_id in the database

Comment: As long as all your target clients set the References header.  Unfortunately, this is client set, and not really a function of the server.  Good luck!